# android:onClick working on double click

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt, bluestacks

I am working on an android application, Eclipse IDE + ADT, targeting API number 17 and debugging on BlueStacks.
I have to trigger certain actions on the click of a button, for that I am using a method in the activity class, and in the XML code I am using this:

```
    android:onClick="myCoolMethod"
```

And it seems to work OK, but it works always after a second click on the button.
My question is:
Is this supposed to be this way given the attribute? If so, is there another attribute that responds to the first click?
If not, why is it not responding to the first click, and what can I do to solve it?

In response to comments:

```
    public void myCoolMethod(View v){
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v==findViewById(R.id.button1)){
            Intent inta = new Intent(MainActivity.this, datainsert.class);
            startActivity(inta);
            }
        }
   });
```

And yes, it is a standalone button.

Comment: No, this isn't how it's supposed to work. I suspect something is wrong in `myCoolMethod()`. Please post its code. I also suggest setting a breakpoint or adding a `Log.d()` call to `myCoolMethod()` to check when it is called.

Comment: "myCoolMethod" is thread or a simple method , will you please post this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the on click listener twice! Remove the on click listener from my cool method and it will work

```
public void myCoolMethod(View v){
        Intent inta = new Intent(MainActivity.this, datainsert.class);
        startActivity(inta);
}
```

I hope you see why this is happening. You first set the onclick in XML. Then set it again once the first click happens (only this time programatically) so it overrides the first onclick. So only after the second click the intent is sent. Program functions as intended. Just use the code above to fix

Comment: I suspected the error was there, yet I tried to fix it in the past and random errors started showing in logcat.
However, I tried again aaaaand magic! It worked.
Thanks, lovehearts for you, good sir ♥

Answer (score 0):

Is this button inside a ListView item? Or is this button a stand alone?
Sometimes it conflicts with ListView onItemClick, similar with Checkbox and ListView onItemClick.

```
Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Search);             
btnSearch.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
{           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Do Button Clicked    
    }           
});
```